# Disable ESC key to scroll viewport in IDE editor

Tags: netbeans

I'm using NetBeans 12.1 on Windows 10 with no plugins or other special setup. When editing any type of text file, pressing the escape key switches to a mode where the cursor keys scroll the viewport instead of moving the cursor. (In many editors, including NetBeans itself, this is typically done by Ctrl-cursor). Pressing escape again leaves that mode and returns to normal.

I often need to press escape to dismiss some window and frequently enter this mode by mistake. I then press the cursor keys to move the cursor but move the viewport instead.

I looked through key bindings to disable the binding, but couldn't find anything. How can I make NetBeans simply ignore the escape key in normal editing mode?